# how to listene for variable change in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I want to run a function when a variable changes its value for example
I have a variable called 'v1' the default value is ZERO
Let's say I have GUI app and I press button, this button only has one function that add one to 'v1' I want another function run when it detects v1 had been change like
`print('v1 change')`, run when a button click or user input or anything that can change its value , JavaScript has `onchange` function dose python has something like that?

Comment: Depends on which GUI framework you use. In Tkinter for example the functionality you describe is built-in and at the core of variable handling.

Comment: A search term that might help you further is 'callback'.

Comment: This isn't something that's available with arbitrarily variables in Python (any more than it is in JS -- `onchange` is an attribute of specific DOM objects, not arbitrary JS variables), but every GUI framework will have some version of `onchange` for objects that represent mutable values.  Pick one of them and read a tutorial on implementing a pushbutton and it will probably have an example very much like what you describe.

Comment: standard variable doesn't have this functionality in Python. Some GUIs use special classes to keep values (and they may need method `.get()`, `.set()` to works with value) and they have also method to assign functions which can be executed when value will be changed - these functions are called `callbacks`. Some GUIs may have it more complex - variable may send event to mainloop and mainloop may check if some `callback` is assigned to this event and execute this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard variables in Python don't have this functionality.

Some GUIs use special class(es) to keep value - and it may need to use functions to `get` and `set` value in class. And it has method to add functions which should be executed when variable change value. These added functions are called `callbacks`

---

Minimal working example

```
class Var:
    
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        
        self._value = value
        self._callbacks = []
        
    def set(self, value):
        old_value = self._value
        self._value = value

        # execute functions when it set value
        for func in self._callbacks:
            func(old_value, value)
        
    def get(self, value):
        return self._value
    
    def add_callback(self, func):
        if func not in self._callbacks:
            self._callbacks.append(func)

    def remove_callback(self, func):
        if func in self._callbacks:
            self._callbacks.remove(func)

def myfunc(old, new):
    print("changed:", old, new)
    
v = Var()

v.add_callback(myfunc)

v.set(10)   # changed: 0 10
v.set(-10)  # changed: 10 -10

v.remove_callback(myfunc)

v.set(0)    # without text
```